# Request for confirmation before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner web developer. I have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).find('form').submit();"><i class="removeItem far fa-trash-alt"></i><form action="http://domain.test/_admin/products/destroy" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="O94UFcB8Woh5BmH7zGZID1lR3Pz4J1wAIrcoJGmw"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"></form></a>
```

It's work fine. I have this in my DataTables.js

I would like to add to my code the question "Are you sure you want to delete this. Record?" yes / no

How can this be done in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello maybe you can add an function with a if and a confirm().
If the user click on OK delet else stop the launch.

```js
function confirmMessage() {
    if ( confirm( "Are you sure to want delet this ? " ) ) {
        // Code for submit if the user click on "OK"
        // maybe
        // document.forms["yourForm"].submit();
    } else {
       // Code if the user click on "cancel"
}
```

And you can launch the function in your on click i think.
Maybe add à name for your form for can sélect it in the function.

Comment: Where do you have create your function ?